# How to create this search action

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with many forms of the following format:

```
<form id="new_celebration100001237275604" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/celebrations" method="post">
    <input id="friend" type="hidden" name="celebrant_details" value="%7B%22name%22%3A%22Venessa%20Stackpole%22%2C%22provider_user_id%22%3A%22100001237275604%22%2C%22birthday%22%3A%2212/10%22%2C%22provider_name%22%3A%22Facebook%22%7D">
    <input id="manager" type="hidden" name="manager_details" value="%7B%22name%22%3A%22Mitchell%20Gould%22%2C%22provider_user_id%22%3A%22751640040%22%2C%22birthday%22%3A%2210/07/1967%22%2C%22email%22%3A%22mitchellgould7@gmail.com%22%2C%22provider_name%22%3A%22Facebook%22%7D">
    <li>Venessa Stackpole</li>
    <li>12/10</li>
    <li>
    <img src="http://graph.facebook.com/100001237244444/picture">
    </li>
    <input class="button-mini-subtle submit" type="submit" alt="select" value="select">
    </form>
```

As the page may contain hundreds of these I want to give the user a search box.
When they start typing in the box I want to hide the forms and data for users that do not match those letters making it easier for them to find their friends.

I am a NOOB and would really appreciate some help to point me in the right direction on this.
Each form has a unique ID as shown. However I don't know how to select the forms based on the value of say the `<li>User Name</li>`

I would like to be able to do this with jquery if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example. You can see it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/zaw65/4/)

**HTML** #searchBox added

**Javascript**

```
var $forms = $('form');
$(function() {
    $('#searchBox').keyup(function() {
        var $form, needle = $(this).val().toLowerCase(), haystack;
        $forms.each(function() {
            $form = $(this);
            haystack = $form.find('li:first').text().toLowerCase();
            $form.toggle(haystack.indexOf(needle) > -1);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Emre Erkan, I will give this a go. It looks great. I will report back and thank you very much. I like the needle in the haystack idea :)

Comment: Hey I tried it out and the $forms.each(function(){ ... does not seem to fire as if its not looping. I tried doing a test alert($forms) which yields object Object.  As  NOOB I don't know how to look at the contents of object Object though :(

Answer (score 0):

Usually I will give a class to your `li`, e.g:

```
<li class="username">User Name</li>
```

Then use '$("li.username")' to find all the `li`s and filter. For filter you will need to create a new `RegEx` object base on user input and match against the text inside the `li`. Then  do a `parentUntil("form")` on filtered `li` to find the form.

I have not touched jQuery for quite a while and may have some mistakes in the syntax. But the approach should be correct as I use it in multiple instances.